# AngularJS - exclude array key in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, filter

I have the following array: I get the key's and generate select inputs based on the keys and the options are the values. So in the end I have four select / dropdowns and each with two values.

```
{
  sku: "401150201025",
  test1: "2,0x1,0",
  test12: "2,5",
  test13: "15,0"
},
{
  sku: "401060120714",
  test1: "1,2x0,7",
  test12: "1,4",
  test13: "6,0"
}
```

How can I filter the "sku" key, so that no "sku" select apprears.

```
  <fieldset class="form-group" ng-repeat="(filterName, values) in availableFilters">
    <label class="pull-left"><% filterName %></label>
    <select class="form-control configurator-radio form-control-lg" ng-model="filter[filterName]">
        <option value="!" selected>Alle</option>
        <option value="<% value %>" ng-repeat="value in values"><% value %></option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
```

This is how I generate the dropdowns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming filterName will be 'sku' at one of the iterations inside ng-repeat you can use ng-if to not display it. It won't be added to the DOM at all.

```
<select ng-if="filterName != 'sku'" class="form-control configurator-radio form-control-lg" ng-model="filter[filterName]">
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use ng-show or ng-hide

This lets you show something based on a value.

```
ng-show="value.sku == 'some_sku_value'"
```

You can also use `ng-hide` for pretty much the same thing.